# How can I enable to test Einstein GPT for Developers in My org?

Tags: einstein

Is this even available for Developer Edition org?

Can I test it? Either in DE org or in sandbox?

Is this available to Partners?

Is this available at least as some trial version?

Comment: If you are looking for dates ~Winter 24 or ~Spring 24 for pilot. GA not sure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Einstein GPT](https://www.salesforce.com/news/press-releases/2023/03/07/einstein-generative-ai/) is currently in closed pilot. Once this is available to use then it will be published globally with a overview of all the relevant details.

[image]

However, you can sign-up and fill this [form](https://www.salesforce.com/form/einstein-gpt/contact-us/) to learn.

Comment: thanks. I struggled to find this information